# Present Simple vs Present Progressive

Tags: meaning, present-continuous, present-simple

What is the difference in meaning between the following two sentences?

> (1) I am completely honest with you right now.
>
> (2) I am **being** completely honest with you right now.

Comment: Are these sentences you've made up yourself or ones you've found somewhere? I don't believe the first one is actually correct, use wise. The form "I am completely ____ with you" is generally fine but I don't think we can use it for "honest".

Comment: @Catija, care to explain why you wouldn't use it for honest? If someone were to say "I am completely honest with you" leaving aside *right now*, I'd assume they are **always** honest with me. On the other hand, "I am being completely honest with you" would simply express in that precise moment.

Comment: @NicholasJ. Maybe it's the "completely". It just sounds odd. I'd say "I'm always honest with you"...

Comment: @Catija it sounds pretty normal to me. Even I've said things such as "I haven't been completely honest with you", not sure if it only sounds odd to you because of it being present tense, but I'd really see no problem with it.

Comment: @NicholasJ. Ok. It wasn't an answer... Clearly we disagree. You're also ignoring the rest of the sentence which is half of what sounds odd.

Comment: @Catija Ayup. It's that *right now* that makes the first sentence so odd.

Comment: @Catija I only ignored the rest of the sentence because of your pointing out the form "I am completely __ with you", but I wasn't saying you're wrong, merely trying to see it from your perspective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Verbs like *be* and *know* and *see*, which express a state are far less likely to be cast in the progressive than verbs which express an action or event. The primary effect of the progressive construction is to "recategorize" an event or action as a continuing state, so its use with stative verbs is superfluous.

When stative verbs *are* cast in the progressive it usually signals one of two things: either the "state" is regarded as temporary and likely to end soon, or the verb has been recategorized semantically: it has a different sense in the progressive.

In the case of *be*, both these changes take place with the progressive: *be* is understood in the sense *behave*, and the behavior expressed is understood to be temporary rather than a permanent characteristic. For instance,

> Brian is a jerk *means that Brian is always a jerk, but*
>   Brian is **being** a jerk *means that right now Brian is behaving like a jerk.*

So it is one thing to say *I am completely honest with you*—this is the ordinary stative use of *be* and implies that I am *always* completely honest with you. It is a permanent aspect of my character.  But *I am completely honest with you **right now*** is odd and jarring, because bare *am* and *right now* imply two different time scopes.

But saying *I **am being** completely honest with you right now* is idiomatic. This says that even if I may not always be completely honest with you or with other people, what I am saying and doing ***right now***—my current behavior—is in fact completely honest.

---

<sup>†</sup> And in fact the only reason I would say this would be if you gave some indication that you believed I was *not* being honest with you.